# pyqt4 QLineEdit realtime output using other py module

Tags: python, module, pyqt4, real-time

i want to show dialog like this:

test 0

test 1

test 2

test 3

........

test success

i try..... but it do not working!

it show only success....

is there way to output during execution by realtime?

this is example code

test.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import test2
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Dialog', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.le = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(130, 22)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        self.le.setText(test2.main("10",self.le))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

test2.py

```
import time

def main(num,text_edit_box):
    for i in range(int(num)):
        text_edit_box.setText(str(i))
        print i
        time.sleep(1)
    return "success"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using `processEvents`. Often when code runs continuously (e.g. like in your for loop in `test2.main`) the program is never told to update, so it doesn't. `processEvents` is the simple way to force a GUI update. It must be called on the `QApplication` class, so I've included a reference to that (`app`) that is passed along to `test2.main`.

`test.py`

```
import sys
import test2
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Dialog', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.le = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(130, 22)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        self.le.setText(test2.main("10",self.le, self.app))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`test2.py`

```
import time

def main(num,text_edit_box, app):
    for i in range(int(num)):
        text_edit_box.setText(str(i))
        print i
        time.sleep(.1)
        app.processEvents()
    return "success"
```

Depending on what you are trying to this may not be the best method, but it's the simplest way to just make your code work.

A better overall method to redraw the GUI might be to have an `update_gui` method in your GUI class that can be called either directly by other modules, or a slot that listens for signals sent by other modules.

Comment: Thanks, I might put that on my resume ;-)